# Is there any alternative for this query which would take lesser processing time

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: Source Table]

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
(
     requestTime datetime2,
     NoOfSessions integer

)

INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE
select  convert(nvarchar(16), TimeLog, 120) requestTime , COUNT(DISTINCT SessionId)As NoOfSessions
from  LogData
group by convert(nvarchar(16), TimeLog, 120) order by requestTime;


select  s1.requestTime
,       (
        select  sum(NoOfSessions)
        from    #TEMPTABLE s2
        where   dateadd(minute, -15, s1.requestTime) < s2.requestTime
                and s2.requestTime <= s1.requestTime
        ) as TotalNumberOfSessions
from    #TEMPTABLE s1


DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: Please provide query plan, index explanation.

Comment: @TomTom The plan is to obtain number of distinct sessions in last 15 mins every minute

Comment: The "PLAN" I mean is not your idea in your head, but a picture of the used QUERY EXECUTION PLAN. That shows us how sql server is executing the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and let me know. It might be some improvement for you.
I added a primary key on `requestTime` in the temp table that can be used in the correlated sub query.

```
create table #TEMPTABLE
(
  requestTime smalldatetime primary key,
  NoOfSessions integer
)

insert into #TEMPTABLE
select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, TimeLog), 0), 
       count(distinct SessionId)
from  LogData
group by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, TimeLog), 0)


select  s1.requestTime
,       (
        select  sum(NoOfSessions)
        from    #TEMPTABLE s2
        where   dateadd(minute, -15, s1.requestTime) < s2.requestTime
                and s2.requestTime <= s1.requestTime
        ) as TotalNumberOfSessions
from    #TEMPTABLE s1

drop table #TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: be aware that this query returns slightly different results to the original, as `cast(getdate() as smalldatetime)` is not quie the same as `convert(nvarchar(16), getdate(), 120)` - use `cast(convert(nvarchar(16), LogDate, 120) as smalldatetime)` to get exactly the same results but more quickly

Comment: @paul That is true. I have updated the answer with what *I* believe is the fastest way to truncate to minutes.

Comment: @Mikeal yes, your new way is certainly seems quicker than the `cast/convert`

Comment: @MikaelEriksson This is really very kool .... Thanks a lot budyyy .... But I hope this doest not keep increasing the tempdb.mdf file

Comment: Oh nice idea. It doesn't fix the loop join but it seems to be enough. A quick fix.

Comment: @usr Yes, the loop join goes against a clustered index seek instead of a table scan. Despite other answers, I think that the temp table is really good option to use here. It will limit the number of rows to sum for each iteration to 15. In SQL Server 2012 you could do this with `sum(NoOfSessions) over(order by requestTime rows between 14 preceding and current row)`. And of course use a numbers table in the first query to make sure you get one row for each minute even if there are no records in `LogData`.

Answer (score 0):

- Drop the TempTable and do it all in ONE select. This totally means you can get the first resuults a LOT faster of possible - SQL Server can in your case not deliver ONE line before the second select happens.
- DO ttry to avoid the Convert. Why do you convert in the first palce?
- Check query plan. YOu tell us nothing about indices and why you think it is slow - more info here may help with the answer.

In general, the problem likely is this:

> where   dateadd(minute, -15, s1.requestTime) < s2.requestTime

I am not sure this can result in an efficient query plan - but then you do not show us the plan.

Comment: I think it may be slow because it has create temp able . Is there a way with which all can be done in a single query .

Comment: Sure. Just - do it. You can use a query (select) instead of a table name

Comment: But what will be the query in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

The temp table is not the problem. The problem is the correlated subquery causing an insane number of loop-join iterations.

Try reformulating the subquery as a join. Round the datetime value to minutes and join on the minutes value.

Comment: Please can anyone write the query for me ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the temp table is the problem, but here's your code without it:

```
select  s1.requestTime
,   (
    select  sum(NoOfSessions)
    from
    (
        select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, TimeLog), 0), 
            count(distinct SessionId)
        from  LogData
        group by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, TimeLog), 0)
    ) s2
    where   dateadd(minute, -15, s1.requestTime) < s2.requestTime
            and s2.requestTime <= s1.requestTime
    ) as TotalNumberOfSessions
from 
(
    select dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, TimeLog), 0), 
        count(distinct SessionId)
    from  LogData
    group by dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, TimeLog), 0)
) s1
```